# Sorting a std::vector with a compare functor which has access to class members

Tags: c++, sorting, friend

I want to sort out a vector using std::sort with self-defined comparison function/functor. Inside this function I always want to have access functions or variables defined within the class.

```
Class MainClass
{
    protected: // Variables
        float fixedpoint;

    protected: // Methods
        float DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(float,float);
        void function1();

    struct CompareDistanceToGoal : public std::binary_function<float,float,bool>
    {
        bool operator()(float p1, float p2)
        {
            // return ( p1 < p2);
            // I want to use the following code instead of the above
            return DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint,p1) < DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint,p2);
        }
    };
}
```

Inside function1:

```
void MainClass::function1()
{
    std::vector<float> V1;
    std::sort(V1.begin(),V1.end(),MainClass::CompareDistanceToGoal());
}
```

So instead of using "return (p1 < p2)", I want to have access to fixedpoint and maybe DistanceBetweenTwoPoints() function. Is this possible (i.e. using friend identifier somehow)?

Can anybody show me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the `std::binary_function` stuff is deprecated. You don't really need it. But you may want to make `operator()` `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a nested type, `CompareDistanceToGoal` has access to all members of `MainClass`; there's no need to declare it a friend. (Although this is a moderately recent change to the language; a compiler that doesn't implement C++11 might need a friend declaration, `friend CompareDistanceToGoal;`, to match modern behaviour).

However, since these members are non-static, you can't do anything with those members unless you provide a `MainClass` object. Perhaps you want to make them static; or perhaps you want to "capture" an object:

```
struct CompareDistanceToGoal // no need for that binary_function nonsense
{
    MainClass & mc;

    CompareDistanceToGoal(MainClass & mc) : mc(mc) {}

    bool operator()(float p1, float p2)
    {
        return mc.DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(mc.fixedpoint,p1) < 
               mc.DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(mc.fixedpoint,p2);
    }
};

std::sort(V1.begin(),V1.end(),MainClass::CompareDistanceToGoal(some_main_class_object));
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution. Does that mean DistanceBetweenTwoPoints has to be "public"? I was thinking about friend relationship between CompareDistanceToGoal and MainClass in order to access protected member of the MainClass. Can CompareDistanceToGoal still be an inner class of MainClass?

Comment: @JohnYang: I covered that in the first sentence. As a nested type, it can access all members of the outer class (unless your compiler is following ancient rules, in which case you'd need a `friend` declaration).

Comment: That clears my mind. Thanks. I am still using the ancient compiler at the moment. I am having trouble to access DistanceBetweenTwoPoints still because it is actually from a Base class that the MainClass is inherited from. I am not sure how to set friendship in this situation. I should start another question because it is probably becoming a different question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to know what you're trying to do, but this seems to have as much chance of being what you want as anything else... note that `MainClass` stores a `fixedpoint` then provides a functor (no need for a nested class) which is then used by `sort`.  In the code below, it sorts the vector so elements closest to the `MainClass` `fixedpoint` are earlier in the `vector`.  See it running at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0zNyjS).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

class MainClass
{
  public:
    MainClass(float fixedpoint) : fixedpoint_(fixedpoint) { }
    bool operator()(float p1, float p2) const
    {
        float d1 = DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint_,p1);
        float d2 = DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint_,p2);
        return d1 < d2 || d1 == d2 && p1 < p2;
    };

  protected: // Variables
    float fixedpoint_;
    static float DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(float a,float b) { return std::fabs(a - b); }
    void function1();
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v { 1, 3, 4.5, 2.3, 9, 12 };
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), MainClass(9.3));
    for (auto f : v)
        std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can capture value manually

```
struct CompareDistanceToGoal : public std::binary_function<float,float,bool>
{
    float fixedpoint;

    CompareDistanceToGoal(float p) : fixedpoint(p) {}
    bool operator()(float p1, float p2)
    {
        return DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint,p1) < DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint,p2);
    }
};
```

and use it

```
void MainClass::function1()
{
    std::vector<float> V1;
    std::sort(V1.begin(),V1.end(),MainClass::CompareDistanceToGoal(fixedpoint));
}
```

---

or if C++11 is available, use lambda to capture value

```
void MainClass::function1()
{
    std::vector<float> V1;
    std::sort(V1.begin(),V1.end(),[=](float p1, float p2){
        return DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint,p1) < DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(fixedpoint,p2);
    });
}
```

Comment: But `CompareDistanceToGoal` would need a `MainClass` instance to act on.

Comment: @juanchopanza so? `function1` is an instance method

Comment: How does `MainClass::CompareDistanceToGoal(fixedpoint)` get a `MainClass` instance?

Comment: This is not a bad idea except DistanceBetweenTwoPoints must be static I think (at least that is the error being thrown). But if I created a function the same as DistanceBetweenTwoPoints inside CompareDistanceToGoal, this will work fine for my purpose.